# Downloading Google API

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-c2dm

I want to use **C2DM service** of google in order to send and receive messages in Android devices, that requires Google API level 8 or above.I have already updated my ADT Plugins(AVD Manager), but it does not show google APIs level 8 or above in the **available packages**.
Can I download Google APIs(level 8 or above) externally ???
How should I proceed to download Goodle APIs level 8 or above ???

sudhanshu

Comment: You need to launch the Android SDK manager to update the API, not the AVD manager:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#AddingComponents

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse you can start the *Android SDK Manager* from the Windows menu. 
There you can **update your Android SDK to revision 15** and afterwards download the package **Google APIs by Google Inc. API 8**.

Afterwards it will be available within Eclipse.